# What is a Freecell Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property, number-theory

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Freecell Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Freecell Words™ | Not Freecell Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| LAWFUL | LEGAL |
| ASTHMA | HEALTH |
| PAWNS | ROOKS |
| SHOP | KIOSK |
| ALPHA | GAMMA |
| TOFU | SOY |
| VIOLET | LILAC |
| SIXES | TWOS |
| TOILET | LOO |
| MEXICO | CANADA |
| FLOYD | ALEC |
| ORGAN | PIPE |
| FLAME | SMOKE |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Freecell Words™,Not Freecell Words™
LAWFUL,LEGAL
ASTHMA,HEALTH
PAWNS,ROOKS
SHOP,KIOSK
ALPHA,GAMMA
TOFU,SOY
VIOLET,LILAC
SIXES,TWOS
TOILET,LOO
MEXICO,CANADA
FLOYD,ALEC
ORGAN,PIPE
FLAME,SMOKE
```

Comment: Does the 'freecell' refer to chess?

Comment: see my comment above.

Comment: Call @Stiv then.